# How to use razor code in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I don't know how to use the razor code in my asp.net project. I am reading this tutorial [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPnet/webpages_forms.asp) , but when i write the code in my "defaul.aspx" file then it can't run. can any one please tell me that how exactly to use the razor code in ASP.NET

Comment: Did you install the razor packages from Nuget? Razor files end in something like .cshtml

Comment: @BenPretorius NO, i have't installed that, even i don't know how to use the razor in asp.net, i am a bit new in asp.net, can you give some suggestion?

Comment: You might as well start with this:) http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: @BenPretorius can we not use the razor code in ASP.NET WP model?

Comment: You should be able to use it with ASP.NET. It is just a view engine that parse your views. The reason why it is not part of WebForms is the fact that it's core role is focused towards the MVC Pattern.

Comment: @BenPretorius got it...!

Comment: I think you just got confused by reading a w3schools "tutorial". You don't use Razor with ASPX files. If your project uses ASPX then you will not be using Razor.

Comment: Stick with the asp.net/mvc tutorials (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started), I'd stay clear of the ones on w3schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to work with Razor in your asp.net Project, then you should create ".cshtml" file like Page.cshtml, write down all the code of Razor there. WebMatrix is a tool through which you can also create professional website of asp.net, and where you would have to handle the Razor. for further detail please see this liknk [Razor in Asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2)